# Which architure/mindset will be suitable for building a web app that users can purchase features like Azure does?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, architecture

We recently had a new business rule that will require our users to pay for individual modules in our web application. 
So, all the features we build in the application will not apply to all users. Some users can choose to add features that they want. 
I've tried researching into an architecture/mindset to how to approach this development. 
If I could get an idea on how to get started with this.. I would very much appreciate it.

I work with .NET web applications, and Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First list what "objects" or things you need to keep track of.

- Users

  - userid
  - fullname
  - can manage his features?  You said not all users can
  - ...
- Features:

  - featureid
  - description
  - cost
  - ...
- UserHasFeature

  - a link between a user and a feature
  - each line is userid, featureid

Using this you can query which user has what feature. Or list the users that have access to a particular feature.

In your web app, you will need administrator functions:

- users management: add, remove, modify, list
- feature: add, remove, modify, list
- link management: add, remove, list
- Reports: whatever reports you want to have

And user functions:

- user: signin, modify, reset password, view all features, view features the user already has, add a new feature, remove a feature
- reports: total cost of features the user is using, others

Now this is a very quick first draft.  There are a lot of missing requirements:

- approval workflow: can a user modify his features without the approbation of X?
- payment methods
- project number for internal billing
- cost structure: monthly, one time, ...?
- managers can view the features of the employees he manages?
- ...

This to remember:

- Start with objects in your projet.  These become tables.
- Characteristics of the objects become fields in your tables.
- If the same characteristic appears in many object tables, with the same values, consider creating a new table for these.  Ex. in an address, you would not leave the country value as a simple VARCHAR field.  You would link to another table with the country values.
- List the relations.  These become foreign keys, or link tables.
- Split your objects.  So apply 1NF, 2NF and 3NF at least.  It is enough for most applications. (NF == Normal Form).
- Each table and links require administrator pages (CRUD)
- Users have a limited view related to their features only.

This is a huge subject, I could go on and on, but this could get you started.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. This gives me a great place to start from. 
I think the challenge I might face would mapping the features in the codebase to features list in the db.
Thanks once again..